# Auto stop recording if there is no-audio / silence using recorder-js with debounce method

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, debouncing

I am trying to implement idea of debounce to auto stop recording if the threshold of the audio goes below 190 for 1000ms using reactjs or javascript.

but the function stopRecording is not getting executed, I feel the problem is the event loop is not getting time to execute the decounced method that was set, can someone help me fix this.

***please look  "startRecord" and "stopRecord" methods***

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import RecorderJS from 'recorder-js';
import { debounce } from 'lodash';
import { ReactComponent as MicIcon } from '../assets/mic.svg';
import { ReactComponent as StopIcon } from '../assets/stop.svg';
import { ReactComponent as DeleteIcon } from '../assets/delete.svg';

import { getAudioStream, exportBuffer } from '../utilities/audio';

//<audio controls style={{ width: 300, height: 100, verticalAlign: 'sub', display: 'inline-block' }} src={audioURL} />


class Recorder extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      audios: [],
      stream: null,
      recording: false,
      recorder: null,
      answer: "",
      analyserData: { data: [], lineTo: 0 },
    };
    this.startRecord = this.startRecord.bind(this);
    this.stopRecord = this.stopRecord.bind(this);
  }



  async componentDidMount() {
    let stream;

    try {
      stream = await getAudioStream();
    } catch (error) {
      // Users browser doesn't support audio.
      // Add your handler here.
      console.log(error);
    }

    this.setState({ stream });
  }


  startRecord() {
    const { stream } = this.state;

    const audioContext = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
    const recorder = new RecorderJS(audioContext, {
      onAnalysed: data => {

        this.setState({ analyserData: data });
        console.log(data.lineTo)
        //trying to set decounce here -------------->
        if (data.lineTo < 200) {
          console.log('debounced');
          this.debounceEvent(this.stopRecord, 500);
        } else{
          
          this.debounceEvent.cancel();
          
        }
      }
    });


    recorder.init(stream);

    this.setState(
      {
        recorder,
        recording: true
      },
      () => {
        recorder.start();
      }
    );

  }

  debounceEvent(...args) {
    this.debounceEvent = debounce(...args);
    return e => {
      e.persist();
      return this.debounceEvent(e);
    };
  }

  async stopRecord() {
    const { recorder } = this.state;
    let answer = "";

    const { buffer } = await recorder.stop()
    const blob = exportBuffer(buffer[0]);

    //send audio to server 
    //
    //
    
    this.setState({ answer: answer })
    // generate video url from blob
    const audioURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    // append videoURL to list of saved videos for rendering
    const audios = this.state.audios.concat([audioURL]);
    this.setState({ audios });

    this.setState({
      recording: false
    });
    //this.debounceEvent.cancel();
  }

  deleteAudio(audioURL) {
    // filter out current videoURL from the list of saved videos
    this.setState({ answer: '' });
    const audios = this.state.audios.filter(a => a !== audioURL);
    this.setState({ audios });
  }


  render() {
    const { recording, stream, audios, answer } = this.state;

    // Don't show record button if their browser doesn't support it.
    if (!stream) {
      return null;
    }

    return (
      <div className="camera">
        <audio
          style={{ width: 400 }}
          ref={a => {
            this.audio = a;
          }}>
          <p>Audio stream not available. </p>
        </audio>
        <div

        >
          {!recording && <MicIcon style={{ width: 34, height: 34 }} onClick={() => this.startRecord()} />}
          {recording && <StopIcon style={{ width: 34, height: 34 }} onClick={() => this.stopRecord()} />}
        </div>
        <div>
          <h1>{answer}</h1>
          {audios.map((audioURL, i) => (
            <div key={`audio_${i}`}>
              <audio controls style={{ width: 200 }} src={audioURL} />
              <DeleteIcon style={{ width: 24, height: 24, verticalAlign: 'middle' }} onClick={() => this.deleteAudio(audioURL)} />
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>

    );
  }
}

export default Recorder;
```

Adding the short main parts of above code for visibility

```
  startRecord() {
    const { stream } = this.state;

    const audioContext = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
    const recorder = new RecorderJS(audioContext, {
      onAnalysed: data => {

        this.setState({ analyserData: data });
        console.log(data.lineTo)
        //trying to set decounce here -------------->
        if (data.lineTo < 200) {
          console.log('debounced');
          this.debounceEvent(this.stopRecord, 500);
        } else{
          
          this.debounceEvent.cancel();
          
        }
      }
    });


    recorder.init(stream);

    this.setState(
      {
        recorder,
        recording: true
      },
      () => {
        recorder.start();
      }
    );

  }

  debounceEvent(...args) {
    this.debounceEvent = debounce(...args);
    return e => {
      e.persist();
      return this.debounceEvent(e);
    };
  }

  async stopRecord() {
    const { recorder } = this.state;
    let answer = "";

    const { buffer } = await recorder.stop()
    const blob = exportBuffer(buffer[0]);

    //send audio to server 
    //
    //
    
    this.setState({ answer: answer })
    // generate video url from blob
    const audioURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    // append videoURL to list of saved videos for rendering
    const audios = this.state.audios.concat([audioURL]);
    this.setState({ audios });

    this.setState({
      recording: false
    });
    //this.debounceEvent.cancel();
  }
```